# Doing TDD in Haskell-mode Emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs

Im trying to set up Emacs for my Haskell workflow, what I'm missing the most is to have my Tasty suit run when I press C-c C-t and display in the mini buffer the status of my tests.

What I have so far is I'm trying to use `haskell-process-cabal` to specify `configure --enable-tests` and then `build`. Im sure there must be some better built in way of running tests easily and getting feedback about coverage etc.